# Copy constructor for a stack using linked list

Tags: c++

```
template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(const Stack<T>& otherStack)
{
        List<T> the=otherStack.list;
        ListItem<T> *temp=the.getHead();
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
                push(temp->value);
                temp=temp->next;
        }
}
```

I am using a linked list to make a stack and my copy constructor is not working. Please someone help.

The copy constructor of `List<T>` is defined as:

```
template <class T>
List<T>::List(const List<T>& otherList)
{
    head=NULL;
    ListItem<T> *temp=otherList.head;

    while (temp!=NULL)
    {
        insertAtTail(temp->value);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: **What** is not working? I mean: How do you know that it isn't working? Unexpected results? Crash? Compile error? Coffee empty?

Comment: Also, what is the definition of `Stack`?

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: I guess it is not compiling - the line with where `the` is assigned probably.

Comment: it's not working because I have checked it using a test file which will show marks if it worked correctly

Comment: @user2064907 That's not very analytical of you.

Comment: @user2064907, here's what we need to answer your question: 1. what are the symptoms of the problem? ("not working" doesn't describe anything). 2. What is the implementation of `List`, `ListItem`, `getHead` and `push`? 3. What did you expect to happen when running this code and what actually happened? 4. What is your test file/test code like?

Comment: @sftrabbit i didnt get u

Comment: @user2064907: Neither did we get your answer

Comment: Can your class `List` copy properly? Since you do it already. And copy elements from that copy in your stack.

Comment: Here's what we need to answer your question: 1. a question.

Comment: @utnapistim ListItem is the node name. getHead is a function to get the head of the linked list. List is the linked list. The thing that should happen after running is i should get marks but it appears 0/5

Comment: @user2064907 - Here are some guidelines that might help: http://sscce.org/

Comment: should I post the copy constructor of my linked list too?

Comment: @user2064907: It would help. As leemes answered below, it could be that the whole implementation in Stack constructor could be a constructor/initializer list call to List constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If `List` and `Stack` have their usual semantics, your constructor reverses order of items in constructed object. So you should either traverse list in reverse order or do such copy twice to restore original order. It is also possible that `List` can be just copied with assignment operator and

```
this.list = otherStack.list
```

is enough. But not seeing `List` code I can't tell.

Comment: Thanks everybody my problem is solved :) thnx for your help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `list` is the only member of `Stack` (since it is enough), and that `List` already has a correct copy constructor implemented, you currently are copying the list with the first assignment:

```
template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(const Stack<T>& otherStack)
{
        List<T> the=otherStack.list;        // <-- list is copied
        ListItem<T> *temp=the.getHead();
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
                push(temp->value);
                temp=temp->next;
        }
}
```

After taking a copy of the whole list, you are pushing the elements of that copy onto your stack. But just copying the list into the member `list` (or better said: initializing `list` with the list of the `otherStack`) is enough to copy the whole stack:

```
template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(const Stack<T>& otherStack) :
    list (otherStack.list)  // <--- list is copied
{
}
```

This might very well just "move" the problem to the copy-construction of `List`.

Comment: it is still showing zero marks

Comment: I don't know how you display your data structure. Please provide the code for the copy c'tor of `List`, since the problem most probably is there.

Comment: template <class T>
List<T>::List(const List<T>& otherList)
{
        head=NULL;
        ListItem<T> *temp=otherList.head;
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
                insertAtTail(temp->value);
                temp=temp->next;
        }

}

Comment: Thanks everybody my problem is solved :) thnx for your help

Answer (score -1):

the code fragment is not enough to identity the issue.
For example line:

```
List<T> the=otherStack.list;
```

makes a copy of the list, if the linked list implementation is custom maybe its copy constructor has issues.
Try

```
List<T> &the=otherStack.list;
```

Comment: If `List` has issues, `Stack` shouldn't work around them. He should fix the issues of `List` and just use a copy of the list to construct a copy of the stack.

Comment: Thanks everybody my problem is solved :) thnx for your help